# I am getting an array from JSON and value from the input field when I written logic to the input value is contained array it always returns false

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on a project. I am getting an array from JSON and value from the input field when I written logic to the input value is contained array it always returns false.

When I tried returns true or false based on the input value. But the problem is when I implemented the logic into my angular project it's always returns "false"

Here is an example code:

```
const arrayJSON = ["122318", "196035", "1242865"];
const inputField = 1242865;
const isAvailable = arrayJSON.includes(JSON.stringify(inputField));

console.log('The value is available', isAvailable);
```

This code return true or false in my local Please find the attachement
[image]

[image]

When I implemented same logic in my angular project always getting "false" only. What I missed here.

here is the angular code:

```
    const inputValue = this.producerAddRemove().value;
    const isAvailable = this.dataSource.data.map(res => res.ProducerID);
    const isTrue = isAvailable.includes(JSON.stringify(inputValue));

    console.log('is the value existing ', isTrue);
```

Update:
  I just removed JSON.stingify(inputValue) and added only inputValue as per  @randomSoul comment. Because the input value already in a string so we don't want to convert again. Thank you all.

Comment: Can you share an example via stackblitz?

Comment: It seems like `isAvailable ` have `id` in `int` type whereas `inputValue` is in `string` and you are applying `JSON.stringify` on `inputValue` which is already in `string`. Instead you can convert your `inputValue` to `int` using `parseInt(inputValue) ` and then use `includes`.

Comment: randomSoul. You are right the input value already in string :). I removed JSON.stringify now working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise to use built in function [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to determine whether array contains value or not:

```js
const arrayJSON = ["122318", "196035", "1242865"];
const inputField = 1242865;
const isAvailable = arrayJSON.indexOf(inputField.toString()) !== -1;

console.log('The value is available', isAvailable);
```